# htaaccess rewrite and removing words space

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problem with rewrite and space betwen words, for example my url looks like this

```
http://xxxsite.com/search/test-test2/
```

and i'm rewrite this with

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/$ index.php?mode=search&q=$1&type=text [L]
```

but now i can see in google webmaster tool some duplicated url's as problem

```
http://xxxsite.com/search/test-test2/
http://xxxsite.com/search/test test2/
```

So as you can see 2nd url is problem, i need to remove/replace space with - as example above

I'm try redirect url with space to new one

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/search/(.*)\s(.*)/$ http://xxxsite.com/search/$1-$2/
```

but this for some reason not working..

There is any chance to remove space and replace it

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to recursively replace all spaces by hyphens:

```
RewriteRule "^([^ ]*) +([^ ]* .*)$" /$1-$2 [L]
RewriteRule "^([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes it's working good, but what if i have 3 words in url or more, or just one word for example and space at the end ?

Comment: It should replace all spaces by hyphens, test it out and tell me for which URL it doesn't work.

Comment: I will check back in few hours.

Comment: for example this url does not working
http://xxxsite.com/search/test test2 test3/

Comment: Try edited code, I tested it with `/search/test test2 test3/` and it became `/search/test-test2-test3/`

Comment: It's not works for me, but im found solution


`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)

RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]

RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]`

Comment: Yes I posted that in my old answer but newer apache servers don't need DPI flag.